# Pytest junit-xml report doesn't have "file" field

Tags: python, xml, pytest

I'm expecting my junit-xml to look like this:

```
<testcase classname="tests.contract.test_dummy_event.TestDummyClass" file="tests/contract/test_dummy_event.py" line="40" name="test_dummy_event" time="0.046"/>
```

However, my junit-xml report looks like this:

```
<testcase classname="tests.contract.test_dummy_event.TestDummyClass" name="test_dummy_event" time="0.046"/>
```

As you can see, the "file" and "line" fields are missing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Config details:

```
Python: '3.6.8'
Platform: 'Linux-4.15.0-1077-aws-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial'
Packages: {'pytest': '6.1.1', 'py': '1.9.0', 'pluggy': '0.13.1'}
Plugins: {'mock': '3.3.1', 'cov': '2.10.1', 'timeout': '1.4.2', 'html': '2.1.1', 'metadata': '1.10.0', 'django': '3.9.0'}
```

This is the command I'm running to generate junit xml:

```
pytest test_dummy_event.py --junit-xml=junit_report.xml
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, it turns out this has to do with `junit_family` settings in `pytest.ini`.

From `pytest >= 6.1.0`, the default value for `junit_family=xunit2`, however the format I was looking for is apparently `junit_family=xunit1`.

Once I added the `junit_family=xunit1` to `pytest.ini`, it generated the report that I was hoping for.

PS: It seems like CicleCI test parallelization using `circleci tests split --split-by=timings` needs `junit_family=xunit1` to work.

Comment: the PS is the most important part!